# Scraping product title off amazon.ca

Tags: python, scrapy

I am working with this link: https://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=ssd
I would like help retrieving product titles off amazon. I have tried a million ways xpath and css and cannot retrieve the product titles of these items. I have looked online to see how others do it but the html is different compared to theirs on this link.(Sorry if indenting off, tried to do it manually as it pasted without proper indentation).

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider
class SSDSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "SSD_spider"
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.ca/ssd/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Assd','https://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=sr_pg_2? rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Assd&page=2&keywords=ssd&ie=UTF8&qid=1531536732']
    DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 10
    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
                'names': response.xpath('//li[contains(@class,"a-size- base s-incline s-access-title a-text-normal")]/text()').extract(),
              }
```

Comment: While scrapy is a great tool for sites that don't support any sort of API endpoints, is there any reason you can't use Amazons product search api endpoints? Scraping HTML is prone to the exact error you are running into when looking at other examples. If/When they update the sites html generation, your scraping will more than likely fail. API endpoints are usually versioned and less error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Preface

Alrighty, first off, Amazon has API endpoints and I suggest anyone reading this to use them over scraping:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html

**Why use API endpoints over html scraping?**

- If the HTML being scraped changes, your queries could break. Sites like Amazon update constantly and I wouldn't expect a XPath query written today to work a couple months from now.
- With all these fancy JavaScript frameworks, some HTML is not generated until very large payloads of js are sent over and processed.
- Scraping tools usually have very large dependency trails (lots of edge cases need to be handled) and this introduces a high number of unnecessary fail points.

---

### Answering the question as is (via scraping)

XPath query that appears to work as of **07/14/2018** (No promises it will work tomorrow):

`//*/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/@title`

Modified code that appears to work.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider

class SSDSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "SSD_spider"
    DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 10
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.amazon.ca/ssd/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Assd',
            'https://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=sr_pg_2? rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Assd&page=2&keywords=ssd&ie=UTF8&qid=1531536732',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {'names': response.xpath('//*/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/@title').extract(),}
```

Result (07/14/2018):

```
{'names': ['Kingston Digital A400 SSD 120GB SATA 3 2.5” Solid State Drive SA400S37/120G - Increase Performance', 'Kingston Digital A400 SSD 240GB SATA 3 2.5” Solid State Drive SA400S37/240G - Increase Performance', 'WD Blue 3D NAND 500GB PC SSD - SATA III 6 Gb/s 2.5"/7mm Solid State Drive - WDS500G2B0A', 'Samsung 860 Evo 2.5" SATA III 500GB Internal SSD (MZ-76E500B/AM) [US Version]', 'Crucial MX500 500GB 3D NAND SATA 2.5 inch Internal SSD - CT500MX500SSD1(Z)', 'Kingston Digital A400 SSD 480GB SATA 3 2.5” Solid State Drive SA400S37/480G - Increase Performance', 'Kingston Digital120GB UV400 SSD C2C 2.5" SUV400S37/120G', 'Samsung 860 Evo 2.5" SATA III 250GB Internal SSD (MZ-76E250B/AM) [US Version]', 'Samsung 860 EVO 2.5" SATA III 500GB Internal SSD (MZ-76E500B)', 'WD Blue 3D NAND 250GB SATA III 6Gb/s 2.5-inch 7mm Solid State Drive (WDS250G2B0A)', 'TCSunBow 2.5" SATA3 Internal Solid State Drive 60gb SSD for PC Laptop Desktop POS Game Advertising Machine (X3 60GB)', 'Samsung 860 Evo 2.5" SATA III 1TB Internal SSD (MZ-76E1T0B/AM) [US Version]', 'Crucial MX300 525GB 3D NAND SATA 2.5 Inch Internal SSD - CT525MX300SSD1', 'Crucial MX500 250GB 3D NAND SATA 2.5inch Internal SSD - CT250MX500SSD1(Z)', 'Kingston Digital 240GB UV400 SSD C2C 2.5" SUV400S37/240G']}
```

#### Strategy to build/find XPath Queries

Many sites (such as Amazon) go through a very heavy handed HTML generation process. Because of this, creating nice clean XPath queries based on intelligently named classes and ids usually isn't possible. So I usually let another software do the heavy lifting. In this case, chrome has the ability to copy the XPath of an element.

On any chrome web page, right click what you think has the data you want and select "Inspect", then on the highlighted element node in the inspector tool, right click, select "Copy", and finally select "Copy XPath".

I copied the XPath of several elements that had the data I think you are after:

```
//*[@id="result_1"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/h2
//*[@id="result_2"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/h2
//*[@id="result_3"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/h2
...
```

Then removed the query section related to grabbing a single results id and had the following:
`//*/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/h2`

This returns the entire header, and I am assuming you only want the name of the product. It looks like the "title" attribute reliably had a name, so I added that to the XPath query.
`//*/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/h2/@title`

Comment: Thanks. Yes I tried many different xpaths and could not get any to work before now.